# Gulp has stopped injecting the minified files it creates into my index.html. How can I debug the cause?

Tags: javascript, gulp

This is an inherited project that was building and working correctly not long ago and now has stopped injecting app-xxxxxxxx.js and vendor-xxxxxxxx.js script tags.  Instead it is injecting >100 ../bower_components/xxx and app/xxx script tags which do not work correctly in the published application.  The app.js and vendor.js minified files are being created correctly.  Two other developers are working on this project, and one of them retains the old correct behavior and the other is experiencing the same problem I have described but the gulp and index files are the same.  My experience with gulp is limited. How can I determine what's wrong and get the minified files to be injected into index.html? 
 Below is my 'gulp build' file, and the build-comment tags from index.html .

**gulp/build.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function ()
{
    return gulp.src([
            path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
            path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
        ])
        .pipe($.htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            maxLineLength     : 120,
            removeComments    : true
        }))
        .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
            module: 'fuse',
            root  : 'app'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function ()
{
    var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), {read: false});
    var partialsInjectOptions = {
        starttag    : '<!-- inject:partials -->',
        ignorePath  : path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
        addRootSlash: false
    };

    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', {restore: true});
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', {restore: true});
    var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', {restore: true});

    return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.cssnano())
        .pipe($.rev())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
        .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
        .pipe($.uglify({preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense})).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
        .pipe($.rev())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe($.revReplace())
        .pipe(htmlFilter)
        .pipe($.htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            maxLineLength     : 120,
            removeComments    : true
        }))
        .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
        .pipe($.size({
            title    : path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'),
            showFiles: true
        }));
});

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
gulp.task('fonts', function ()
{
    return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
        .pipe($.flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/styles/')));
        //.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function ()
{
    var fileFilter = $.filter(function (file)
    {
        return file.stat.isFile();
    });

    return gulp.src([
            path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
            path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js,scss}')
        ])
        .pipe(fileFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});

gulp.task('clean', function ()
{
    return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')]);
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

**gulp/inject.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var _ = require('lodash');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('inject-reload', ['inject'], function ()
{
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('inject', ['scripts', 'styles'], function ()
{
    var injectStyles = gulp.src([
        path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.css'),
        path.join('!' + conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/vendor.css')
    ], {read: false});

    var injectScripts = gulp.src([
            path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.module.js'),
            path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'),
            path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.spec.js'),
            path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.mock.js'),
        ])
        .pipe($.angularFilesort()).on('error', conf.errorHandler('AngularFilesort'));

    var injectOptions = {
        ignorePath  : [conf.paths.src, path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')],
        addRootSlash: false
    };

    return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/*.html'))
        .pipe($.inject(injectStyles, injectOptions))
        .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, injectOptions))
        .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));
});
```

**index.html snippet**

```
<div id="main" class="animate-slide-up" ui-view="main" layout="column"></div>

<!--<ms-theme-options></ms-theme-options>-->

<!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- inject:partials -->
<!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**Logging from the build...**

```
[13:48:43] Starting 'scripts'...
[13:48:43] Starting 'styles'...
[13:48:44] Starting 'partials'...
[13:48:44] Starting 'fonts'...
[13:48:44] Starting 'other'...
[13:48:46] gulp-inject 57 files into index.scss.
[13:48:47] Finished 'fonts' after 2.48 s
[13:48:56] Finished 'styles' after 13 s
[13:48:57] all files 3.67 MB
[13:48:57] Finished 'scripts' after 14 s
[13:48:57] Starting 'inject'...
injectOptions { ignorePath: [ 'src', '.tmp\\serve' ], addRootSlash: false }
[13:48:57] Finished 'partials' after 14 s
[13:48:57] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
[13:49:00] gulp-inject 347 files into index.html.
[13:49:00] Finished 'inject' after 2.82 s
[13:49:00] Starting 'html'...
[13:49:01] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
[13:49:02] Finished 'other' after 18 s
[13:50:04] dist\ maps\scripts\vendor-152deb66d8.js.map 10.03 MB
[13:50:35] dist\ maps\scripts\app-1c22f6e98b.js.map 6.43 MB
[13:50:35] dist\ index.html 36.51 kB
[13:50:35] dist\ styles\app.css 3.95 MB
[13:50:35] dist\ styles\vendor.css 183.07 kB
[13:50:36] dist\ scripts\vendor-152deb66d8.js 2.31 MB
[13:50:36] dist\ scripts\app-1c22f6e98b.js 2.49 MB
[13:50:36] dist\ all files 25.44 MB
[13:50:36] Finished 'html' after 1.6 min
[13:50:36] Starting 'build'...
[13:50:36] Finished 'build' after 67 μs
```

Comment: I don't see an 'inject' task?

Comment: I've added the inject script to the question.

Comment: Quick question: does the order of completion of these tasks make any difference: gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'] …  Because 'inject' and 'partials" are not guaranteed to finish in nay particular order.  In other words, are those two tasks completely independent of each other?

Comment: @Mark Not sure how to answer.  These files haven't been changed from when they were working.  Some of the npm or bower packages have been updated but none of the gulp files.

Comment: I've added some logging from the build process.  It does show injecting files into index.html before logging out the creation of the scripts/app-xxx.js and scripts/vendor-xxx.js files.

Comment: I see that partials starts before inject and finishes after inject starts.  I was just wondering if that is okay for your build process.  That they do not run or complete in any certain order.  Because they will run in parallel and may start and finish at different times with respect to each other on any given run.  Does that make sense?  I just don't know if that matters to your build process.  It is easy to precisely specify an order for those two tasks if necessary.  Perhaps you should try that.  Likewise I see that scripts and styles do not complete until after partials has begun.

Comment: I just don't know enough about angular and your partials task innards to know if those order of tasks is important.

Comment: This has been resolved, unfortunately we do not know why.  The index.html file was replaced with an older version that was barely different from the current(some hard-coded urls changed and line space formatting).  The build started working, and we then modified that file piece by piece to look exactly like the broken version and still the build worked. If there was a lesson learned here I'm not sure what it was.